# IQueryable<Patron> does not contain a definition for FirstName and no extension method First Name

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I'm starting to learn ASP.NET Core and I stuck in one error and don't understand what is problem. 
It says:

> `IQueryable<Patron>` does not contain a definition for `FirstName` and no extension method `FirstName` accepting a first argument of type `IQueryable<Patron>` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

So my code so far:

**Patron.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace LibaryData.Models
{
   public class Patron
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual LibaryCard LibaryCard { get; set; }
        public virtual LibaryBranch HomeLibaryBranch { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CheckoutServices.cs**

```
using LibaryData;
using LibaryData.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using LibaryData.Models;

namespace LibaryServices
{
    public class ChekoutService : ICheckout
    {
        private LibaryContext _context;

        public ChekoutService(LibaryContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public string GetCurrentCheckoutPatron(int assetId)
        {
            var checkout = GetCheckoutByAssetId(assetId);
            if(checkout == null)
            {
                return "";
            }

            var cardId = checkout.LibaryCard.Id;
            var patron = _context.Patrons
                .Include(p => p.LibaryCard)
                .Where(p => p.LibaryCard.Id == cardId);

            return patron.FirstName + " " + patron.LastName;
        }

        private Checkout GetCheckoutByAssetId(int assetId)
        {
            return _context.Checkouts
                .Include(co => co.LibaryAsset)
                .Include(co => co.LibaryCard)
                .Where(co => co.LibaryAsset.Id == assetId)
                .FirstOrDefault(co => co.LibaryAsset.Id ==assetId);
        }
    }
}
```

So in my class `CheckoutServices` in method `GetCurrentCheckoutPatron` I can not call a object `patron.`**`FirstName`** and `patron.`**`LastName`**
As you can see all classes are public, references is already there.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `.Where` with `.First` to get a `Patron` and not a `IQueryable<Patron>`

---

### Edit

Note that if you use `.First`, an exception can be raised if there's no match.
However, if you use `.FirstOrDefault` and there's no match, it will return `null`, so you'll get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to access `patron.FirstName`.

Be carefull to check for `null`s

Comment: Wouldn't that be simply removing the where condition? That will not give correct result

Comment: @danish, nope, you can use `.First(p => p.LibaryCard.Id == cardId);`

Comment: Insted of Where I just put FirstOrDefault. It works now

Comment: @Rafalon interesting! Didn't knew that.

Comment: @danish same goes for `.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LibraryCard.Id == cardId);`

Answer (score 0):

In your method `GetCurrentCheckoutPatron` the variable `patron` is an `IQueryable`. If you are expecting only single result from the query, you might want to call `FirstOrDefault`.